# How to add 2 string of code together for views in custom module?

Tags: views

I have a view that needs these 2 lines of code:

```
 if($form_id == "views_exposed_form" && $form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-hide-tweaked-advanced')
```

and

```
if($form_id == "views_exposed_form" && $form['#id']=='views-exposed-form-hide-tweak-basic')
```

function:

```
<?php
 function dropdowninteger_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){     
  if($form_id == "views_exposed_form" && $form['#id']=='views-exposed-form-hide-tweaked-advanced'){
     $options = array('1' => '1', '2'=>'2');
     $form['field_user_age_value']['#type'] ='select';
     $form['field_user_age_value']['#size'] = null;
     $form['field_user_age_value']['#default_value'] = '';
     $form['field_user_age_value']['#options'] = $options; 
  } 
}
```

How do I add them together for my custom module? Not sure if my question is clear enough though....

Comment: Please make your code more readable and highlight it using code tags.

Comment: And please tell us why and where exactly that code is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I usually set up my views functions:

```
function dropdowninteger_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){   
  if($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') {
    switch ($form['#id']) {
      case 'views-exposed-form-hide-tweaked-advanced':
        <tweaked-advanced code here>;
        break;
      case 'views-exposed-form-hide-tweak-basic':
        <tweak-basic code here>;
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you don't think this is really a Drupal question, please flag as off topic, not attempt to answer. Answering questions you *know* are bad encourages people to ask more of them. So you are promoting degradation of quality, and you kinda know it...

Comment: @Molot I did both that way hopefully everyone gets something out of it :) If it gets closed it is gone, correct?

Comment: First, two weeks of being on hold. Then, if not fixed and reopened, and  if it's of positive or neutral score with upvoted answers, it stays. If not, or if moderator decides, it's deleted. Then, if moderator or few users over 10k decides it can be salvaged, it can be undeleted and edited. And so on.

Comment: The answer above worked, it was  a PHP question I guess, I looked for Stack Exchange PHP but only found programmers, where should I post stuff like this?

Comment: @BrunoVincent if question is not really about Drupal, but about PHP code, it's best suited for http://stackoverflow.com/ However, your question now have three "unclear what you're asking" votes. This means at least three people with pretty high reputation wasn't able to tell for sure what you need. That's not good. And sorry to say, but if you think your question was poorly received here, Stack Overflow can be even more strict.

Comment: Hi Molot, ok thanks, I'll keep working on my asking skills ;)